# A problem regarding the fragility of multiple windows viewing the same buffer

Tags: neovim, vim-windows

### Problem Statement (concise, but inexact, version)

Windows viewing the same buffer are fragile in the following sense.

Consider a complex arrangement of tens or hundreds of windows, distributed amongst tens of tabs, all viewing different parts of different sections throughout the same large buffer.  When a multi-line section of that buffer is deleted<sup>1</sup>, all windows with their cursor positioned on a line within that section have their cursor moved ***without warning*** to the same line outside the deleted section.

An immediate `:undo`/`:redo` of the delete restores the deleted section to the buffer, but the affected windows' cursors remain positioned on the same line to which they were moved by the delete.  Depending on the size of the buffer and the number of windows viewing it at the time of the delete, this can potentially render *all* (but one of) the windows viewing the same buffer *instantly* useless.  Furthermore, since the affected windows are altered silently, there is a high probability that the affected windows will not be noticed after many subsequent changes (very broadly defined).

1. E.g., by the equivalent, in any mode, of a `:change`, `:delete`, `:join`, `:move`, `:substitute`, `:sort`, `:redo`, `:undo`, `:!`, etc.; in essence, *any* command in *any* mode that results in a call to [`src/memline.c:ml_delete_int`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/de19b745eee06a8a204988ae9989d97143caece9/src/memline.c#L3511) on those lines in that buffer.

### Question

Are there are any solutions to/automated techniques to avoid most instances of this problem?

In particular, I'm curious if Neovim has implemented an appropriate solution/technique/etc. and/or if Neovim has implemented features beyond Vim's that would enable me to easily script something.

Assuming a relatively modern computer, the recommended change should not noticeably impact Vim's performance, at least not with any great frequency, and not even when there are hundreds of windows viewing the same buffer.

### Problem Statement (detailed, but still somewhat inexact, version)

For years now I have been using large (and steadily increasing) numbers of windows and tabs in conjunction with `:mksession` and `vim -S`.  I cannot remember precisely when I began developing these habits<sup>2</sup>, but for as long as I have been relying on the relevant features, I have kept the following selection from `:help tab-page-intro` well in mind:

```
:help tab-page-intro
... ... ...
Tabs are also a nice way to edit a buffer temporarily without changing the
current window layout.  Open a new tab page, do whatever you want to do and
close the tab page.
... ... ...
```

This technique is quite useful, but I have frequently been irked when a mistaken command disrupts multiple windows in a manner that is often not conveniently recoverable.

The type of accidental multi-window disruption I wish to avoid is best demonstrated by an executable example.  Starting with a single window open on an empty unnamed buffer, execute the following commands:

```
:call append(0, split("Line 1.\nLine 2.\nLine 3.\nLine 4.\nLine 5.\nLine 6.\nLine 7.\nLine 8.\nLine 9.\nLine 10.\n", '\n'))
:$delete | redraw!
:silent execute "1 | split | resize 1 | wincmd j | 4 | split | resize 1 | wincmd j | 7 | split | resize 1 | wincmd j | 10 | 2wincmd k | resize"
```

Note the line number of each of the four windows, which is the buffer line number of the associated window's cursor.  I will refer to the buffer line number of a window's cursor as that window's `wcl_lnum`, which is an abbreviation of "window current line line number"<sup>3</sup>.

Now execute the following commands:

```
:tab split
:7,$delete
```

Assume that at this point you realize you've made a mistake: perhaps you should have deleted only the eighth line, for example.  Regardless, before making further edits, you want to undo the mistake and view the original tab.  Execute the following commands:

```
:undo
:quit
```

The screen position, height, and width of each window, i.e., layout without regard to contents, in the first tab are unchanged, as are the `wcl_lnum`s of the first and second windows from the top of the screen; the `wcl_lnum`s of the third and fourth windows, however, are now both `6`, their ordering lost.

This example is simple and contrived, but imagine a much more complex arrangement of windows and tabs viewing the same large file.  Then consider making a single hasty mistake (e.g., deleting the wrong section, for example) that silently obliterates the `wcl_lnum` ordering of tens or even hundreds of windows distributed amongst the non-current (and therefore non-visible at the time the mistake is made) tabs.

Note that there are critical cases where I *expect* `wcl_lnum` ordering to be invalidated and/or lost, particularly those involving a file that is altered outside of the current Vim process (say, by Git) and subsequently reloaded (after a helpful warning) via `:edit`.  I have developed ways of recovering from the `wcl_lnum` disruptions produced in such situations, but these techniques, which can still be somewhat time consuming, depend on preparation, and the only way I know of to prepare for a silent multiple-`wcl_lnum`-flattening mistake is to regularly back up the file produced by `:mksession`<sup>4</sup>.

2. See [locking - Lock some text in vim to prevent modifications - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854390/lock-some-text-in-vim-to-prevent-modifications).  I include a reference to this Stack Overflow post because I have been (obsessively but anonymously) following it since around the time my excessive window/tab habits collided with the problem I (attempt to) describe in the current post.  If the post [locking - Lock some text in vim to prevent modifications - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854390/lock-some-text-in-vim-to-prevent-modifications) is ever answered in the affirmative, the current post will be as well.
3. One might wonder why I don't reference a/the window's cursor or cursor position in this identifier or throughout the rest of this message, for that matter.  I promise I have reasons.
4. I mean literally back up the file produced by `:mksession` to some path other than `v:this_session`.  This is in contrast to [GitHub - tpope/vim-obsession: obsession.vim: continuously updated session files](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession), which, if I remember correctly (though please inform me if I am wrong) uses autocommands to trigger (re)writes to `v:this_session`.

### Full Disclosure, Or, What I Have Already Done

> The above problem finally produced sufficient accumulated aggravation that earlier this year (2020) I went though the effort of developing a patch to circumvent it in the great majority of cases.  An overview of this patch along with a link to it can be found at the `vim-dev@vim.org` Google group conversation [Proposal: "protectncwcleol"/"pncwcleol" option... - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/z2AZ4f-7Oxc) (n.b., the `[URL][TITLE]` pattern I use throughout my original `Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2020 21:57:00 -0700` [plain text message](https://www.vim.org/maillist.php)  to `vim-dev@vim.org` is rendered by both Google Groups and Gmail with broken links; correctly rendered links are provided in the message I post immediately below the original message).  As I state in the aforementioned post to the `vim-dev@vim.org` Google group, the patch is ***entirely provisional***, and any discussion of it should take place elsewhere (e.g., the `vim-dev@vim.org` Google group).  I am posting the current message on the Vi and Vim Stack Exchange because I want to know if there are other solutions to this problem.  In particular, if Neovim provides a solution, please let me know.

Comment: tl;dr.  ....          No no no, I'm joking with you! I read it all. But it does seem pretty verbose and that you could make your point with a lot fewer words. The example could probably be simplified, too. (E.g. you don't need to fill in all those lines, just add a couple empty lines and turn on line numbers; two windows on first tab; maybe use `ugt` instead of `:undo`, `:quit`...those are just off the top of my head but the point is it could fit on a lot fewer lines of your post). Why do I mention this? Because it might put more eyes on your question. Anyways, welcome to Vi-Vim SE.

Comment: @DBenKnoble: Thanks for the editing work.

Comment: Folks, I've nuked the comments here. Comments are for clarification, not extended conversation (which you can take to [chat], including rooms just for this question). If there are issues around behavior, please flag comments for moderator intervention and disengage. We want to maintain a professional & welcoming community here, and we put in a lot of work to make that happen. I must personally apologize if anyone felt attacked or otherwise dismissed; I also believe earnestly that was not anyone's *intent*.  We all have a role to play when conversation turns unproductive.

Comment: Alex, if you feel you can [edit] the question to show what you've tried (path or your own scripts) and why it doesn't work for you, that might help guide us towards what an appropriate solution looks like. Questions like "does neovim's features make scripting this easier" are a little broad/opinion-based/etc. I would suggest a refocusing on the problem at hand, what you've tried, and what's not working (e.g., you don't want to maintain a separate fork, but you can't make vimscript work for you in a particular way)

Comment: @DBenKnoble: Thanks for the recommendations.  I have my notes from 2020JAN16THU and earlier containing the relevant `:yank` `:@"` Vim script experiments I carried out before abandoning Vim script in favour of direct changes to the source code.  It would probably be better if I created a new post for each specific issue: writing them down will take some time, and the current post will grow progressively longer with each addition.  The fate of the current post is of course up to you and the other moderators.